# Get array elements from index to end

Tags: python, vector, numpy, indexing

Suppose we have the following array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1, 10)
a = a.reshape(len(a), 1)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

Now, i want to access the elements from index 4 to the end:

```
a[3:-1]
array([[4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8]])
```

When i do this, the resulting vector is missing the last element, now there are five elements instead of six, why does it happen, and how can i get the last element without appending it?

Expected output:

```
array([[4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The `[:-1]` removes the last element. Instead of

```
a[3:-1]
```

write

```
a[3:]
```

You can read up on Python slicing notation here: [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

NumPy slicing is an extension of that. The NumPy tutorial has some coverage: [Indexing, Slicing and Iterating](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c).

Comment: That worked indeed, thanks, i'm trying to convert some matlab code to python/numpy, and that reference guide [NumPy fot Matlab users](http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) misses some important issues as indexing and slicing.

Comment: @Andfoy: I'd recommend reading the NumPy tutorial I linked to. It's not perfect, but should be a good start.

Comment: Is there an object or other "index" that can go where the -1 is to make it behave like `a[3:]`? I often find it would simplify the code I write..

Comment: I found the answer--use `None`--like `a[3:None]`.