# Excel create array adress according to index to end

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, dynamic

Excel 365 now supports dynamic arrays which are very similar in nature to those supported by most programming languages.

For instance, you can now type =A1:A5*2 in B2 and if the range A:1:A5 contains numeric values they will be multiplied in B1:B5.

My question is can one recognize the "end" of the data in column A and write the multiplication accordingly?

This is similar to what is explained for python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732025/get-array-elements-from-index-to-end) and for MATLAB [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/object-end-indexing.html)

Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if the values in Column A are static or placed by a non dynamic formula:

```
=A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)) * 2
```

[image]

Or FILTER:

```
 =FILTER(A:A,ISNUMBER(A:A)) * 2
```

[image]

If the values in Column A are also filled with a dynamic array then we just need:

```
=A1# * 2
```

In A1 I put `=SEQUENCE(6)`

[image]